# Match strings from dictionary keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

so if I have a dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> namesDictionary= new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Paola", "Perú" },
                { "Paulanos", "Colombia" },
                { "Paulanas", "Ecuador" },
                { "Pamela",  "Venezuela"},
                { "Paulina",  "Brasil)"},
                { "Paolann",  "Paraguay"}
            };
```

And I will have the String name = "" setted by a function.

I want to find and match the name in the dictionary keys, like:

- if name = "paola", it finds "Paola", "Perú" and not "Paolann",  "Paraguay"
- if name = "Paulanoso" finds only { "Paulanos", "Colombia" } and not 
                  { "Paulanas", "Ecuador" },

.NET 2.0
It's not necessary for it to be a dictionary if there is a better option.

Something like character by character like:

- if name = "Paulanoso" (example string, doesnt mean anything) it finds only Paulanos, it doesnt have to match exactly the entire string
- Even if the name string is larger it would do something like:
  name = "Paolanoso123"
  it should find: { "Paulanos", "Colombia" }

Comment: It should be case sensitive though?

Comment: "Paulanoso" matches "Paulanos"? Can you explain what the actual matching algorithm is?

Comment: Paulanoso is a typo I guess

Comment: @EdPlunkett Something like character by character like: if name = "Paulanoso" (example string, doesnt mean anything) it finds only Paulanos, not necessarilythe entire string exactly but if it find char by char even if the name string is larger, not case sensitive.

Comment: @dracarons Please write a complete and unambiguous description of the matching criteria and add that to your question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Edited, please let me know, one of my first questions, thanks.

Comment: That's ambiguous and incomplete. Voting to close as unclear. Strings should substrings but not superstrings?

Comment: How would you match those entries? Do you want to access them using an indexer, like `namesDictionary["Paola"]`? Or do you just want to iterate between them and get matching values? Also, what if there are multiple matches (e.g. `Paola` and `Paol` inside the dictionary and `name = "Paola"`)? Your question is really confusing.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma in that case should return Paola, It should match the most closer one to the name, get the "most closer, matching " value

Comment: You haven't described what **you** intend for the *most closer match*. Also, for what you are asking is impossible to have a solution that doesn't just iterate between each `KeyValuePair`. You didn't answer my question, do you want to access the dictionary by key or like a collection?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma By key, I want to find the country from the names, for example, all the woman whos name is Paola are from Perú, but all the woman's whos name is Paolann are from Paraguay

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the key match to be case sensitive, you can try the following;

```
var collection = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
// fill collection
var value = collection["paola"];
```

However, if you have to match `Paulanoso` to `Paulanos` in the keys, you'll need to implement a custom string comparer with your matching rules.

Comment: Indeed, or if your match algorithm is more complicated you can define your own implementation of IEqualityComparer and pass that in to the constructor of the dictionary.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your matching criteria:

```
var result = namesDictionary
    .FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key.Contains(name) || name.Contains(kv.Key)).Key;
```